# Make css popup activate with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I have this CSS popup that currently is setup with a button. I also have this JavaScript "mouse click counter". What I would like to happen is when the counter gets to zero the popup shows up. I think it is easy I just do not have enough experience in JavaScript. Thanks

CSS Popup

```
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

JavaScript Mouse Click Counter (Starts at 10 and then goes from there)

```
var number = 10;

            document.onclick = function(){
                    number --;
                    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = number;
            }
```

I tend to not clarify things so just to be sure. Once the counter gets down to zero i would like to popup to activate with all the features. Including the screen opaqueness. Thank You!

jsfiddle - mouse click counter
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/2es8bvz9/)

jsfiddle - pop up
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/24nrpg2s/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way checking to see the value of `number`, incrementing `#clicks` if the `number > -1`, and if `number == 0`, update the hash so your popup is shown.

```js
var number = 10;

document.onclick = function() {
  number--;
  if (number > -1) {
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = number;
    (number == 0) && (location.hash = '#popup1')
  }
};
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}


.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clicks"></div>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>WOW!</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
      <center>Lets see how you did!!</center>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm it did not seem to work. Its probably something on my end. where you had <div id="popup">right here</div> I put the html for the actual popup. which was this

Comment: <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>WOW!</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
      <center>Lets see how you did!!</center>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>

Comment: Once it gets to zero it just stays there. the popup wont...well "popup" @MichaelCoker

Comment: @SethChouinard ah, you added your popup code to the post. Without that, I had to assume what you were doing, so I wrote my best guess at what I thought your popup was, and you weren't able to adapt my demo back to your code. In the future, be sure to include all of the relevant code up front. Updated my answer with your popup code.

Comment: Tested the sample above with Firefox 53 and Chrome 58, both works.

Comment: @SethChouinard your website doesn't match the jsfiddle code. It's also not our job to troubleshoot your personal website... you need to accurately reproduce the problem in your post, and we solve the problem in your post.

Comment: It works!!! I was copy and pasting everything over and just got confused in all of the different code. Thank you very much and I apologise for the confusion. Thanks! @MichaelCoker